# $this->getRequest()->getPost() return empty array in magento 2 back end form?

Tags: magento-2.1, adminform

I have tried to create new admin form with Uicomponent then I try this method in my controller $this->getRequest()->getPost() but it return null

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">mass_actions_form.actions_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">mass_actions_form.actions_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sample Form</item>
        <item name="layout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="type" xsi:type="string">tabs</item>
        </item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="back" xsi:type="string">Mass\Actions\Block\Adminhtml\Contact\Edit\BackButton</item>
            <item name="delete" xsi:type="string">Mass\Actions\Block\Adminhtml\Contact\Edit\DeleteButton</item>
            <item name="reset" xsi:type="string">Mass\Actions\Block\Adminhtml\Contact\Edit\ResetButton</item>
         <!-- <item name="save" xsi:type="string">Mass\Actions\Block\Adminhtml\Contact\Edit\SaveButton</item>-->
            <item name="update" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">update</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Save</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">actions/product/SelectedCat</item>
            </item>
            </item>
    </argument>
   <dataSource name="actions_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Mass\Actions\Model\Contact\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">actions_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        </argument>


        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="category">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Assign Categories</item>
            </item>
        </argument>

        <field name="Category_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Category</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">contact</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="category_ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\Form\Categories\Options</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Categories</item>
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/js/components/new-category</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                    <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="listens" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData" xsi:type="string">setParsed</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: write your xml .

Comment: Ok please can u help me any ideas for this

Comment: In your modifier class, there will be issue in modifyData method. please check data return from it. Also please provide your modifier class. So I can check it and provide you solution